# "Push" Object to end of Associative Array in Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to push values to the end of an associative array. The basic layout of the array (with one object in it) is like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [alert] => Array ( [email] => Test ) ) )
```

I'm doing a query on a MySQL database and comparing some data and when there is a match, I'm trying to add the new match to the end of the array ($alert_array). Essentially, I want it to look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [alert] => Array ( [email] => Test ) ) [1] => Array ( [alert] => Array ( [email] => Test ) ) )
```

And so on...depending on how many matches there are. I've got the following code (which is simplified so there are some declarations earlier in the code but I think it can all be inferred from what you're seeing below). You'll note that I've done an `echo 'test'` to have 'test' echoed out every time there is a match. Currently in the code, there are two matches ('test' is echoed out twice) but there is only one object in the array when I print it out. My hunch is that the array runs, adds the first match to the array and then overwrites the array as it finds the second match. I'm trying to 'push' it on the end of the array. I tried `array_push($alert_array, '$alert', '$email')` instead of array('content below') but that didn't work. Can anyone help me? It seems like it should be pretty simple. Thanks!

```
$alert_array = array();

while($row_state_match = mysqli_fetch_array($result_state_match)){
    $city = $row_state_match['city'];
    $email = $row_state_match['email'];

    if($city!="UNDEFINED" && $city==$alert_city){ 

            //TEST TO SEE HOW MANY MATCHES HAPPEN
            echo 'test'; 

            //PUSH ALERT TO ARRAY
            $alert_array[] = array("alert" => "
            <table class='alert' width='600'>
                    <tr width='100%'>
                            <td width='50%'>
                                    <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                            <h1>It worked</h1>
                                                    </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>", "email" => $email);
    }

}
```

Comment: and where exactly do you print `$alert_array` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to push like this to get desired array

```
$basearray=array ( '0' => array ( 'alert' => array ( 'email' => 'Test' ) ) );
$alertarray=array('alert'=>array('email'=>'Test2'));
array_push($basearray,$alertarray);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($basearray);
```

output :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [alert] => Array
                (
                    [email] => Test
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [alert] => Array
                (
                    [email] => Test2
                )
         )
)
```